# How to create Kubernetes load balancer on aws

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2

Kubernetes create a load balancer, for each service; automatically in GCE. How can I manage something similar on AWS?

Kubernetes service basically use the kubeproxy to handle the internal traffic. But that kubeproxy ip its do not have access to the external network.

There its a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your service definition, set its `type` [field](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/7a3891e5f8819456b355750c0603e48da35b895b/pkg/api/v1/types.go#L1097) to `LoadBalancer`, and kubernetes will automatically create an AWS Elastic Load Balancer for you if you're running on AWS. This feature should work on GCE/GKE, AWS, and OpenStack.

For an example, check out the [guestbook-go example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/examples/guestbook-go/guestbook-service.json).

Comment: If I install K8s in my local, how can i have a loadbalancer that is able to work with k8s?

Comment: You can't setup a local loadbalancer with K8S.

Comment: How does it know about the access credentials?

Comment: What about the ports? If I have a service listening on the port 9000, should I access `load-balancer-ip:9000` in order to access the service?

Comment: loadbalancer must use by cloud provider

Answer (score 5):

Minimal example:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 9376
```

The relevant docs:

- [Create an External Load Balancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/)
- [Type LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-loadbalancer)

As of writing the best way to learn about all the `service.beta.kubernetes.io` annotations is to read the source code:

- [cloudprovider/providers/aws/aws.go](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/cloudprovider/providers/aws/aws.go#L96)

For the controller to be able to manage the ELB it will need permissions set in the master instances IAM Role, [e.g.](https://github.com/coreos/tectonic-installer/blob/master/modules/aws/master-asg/master.tf#L119):

```
...
{
  "Action": "elasticloadbalancing:*",
  "Resource": "*",
  "Effect": "Allow"
},
{
  "Action": [
    "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
    "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
    "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
    "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
    "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
    "ecr:ListImages",
    "ecr:BatchGetImage"
  ],
  "Resource": "*",
  "Effect": "Allow"
},
...
```

The cloud provider should be set with `--cloud-provider=aws` on [kube-apiserver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kube-apiserver/).

Comment: what about AWS API Keys?

Comment: when you use IAM role you don't need API key