# How to access kubernetes service load balancer with juju

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, juju

Kubernetes create a load balancer, for each service; automatically in GCE. How can I manage something similar on AWS with juju?

Kubernetes service basically use the kubeproxy to handle the internal traffic. But that kubeproxy ip its do not have access to the external network.

There its a way to accomplish this deploying kubernetes cluster with juju?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create Kubernetes load balancer on aws](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611503/how-to-create-kubernetes-load-balancer-on-aws)

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to juju specifically, but Kubernetes supports Amazon ELB - turning up a load-balancer should work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to accomplish this, but it depends on additional work landing in the Kubernetes charms from the ~Kubernetes charmer team.

While you can reasonably hook it into an AWS ELB - Juju charms strive to be as DC agnostic as possible so its easily portable between data centers and clouds. A 'one size fits most' if you will.

What I see being required, is attaching the kube-proxy service to a load balancer service (Such as nginx) and using a template generator service like confd, or consul-template, to register/render the reverse proxy / load balancer configs for the services.

At present the Kubernetes bundle only has an internally functioning network, and the networking model is undergoing some permutations. If you'd like to participate in this planning + dev cycle, the recommended location to participate is the juju mailing list: juju@lists.ubuntu.com