# how to setup loaderbalancer service of kubernetes in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes

i try to use AWS to setup kubernetes(version 1.0.1) and deploy a few services and pods there.

but i have got stuck with LoadBalancer service. According to the docs i just need to setup correct type of service and open ports in firewall

But service doesn't receive external IP. (ingress is empty)

Do i need to create LoadBalancer manually in AWS console? maybe some another actions?

Thanks,

Comment: what does `kubectl describe service <your service>`  output?

Comment: `Name:                   main  
Namespace:              default  
Labels:                 name=main  
Selector:               name=main  
Type:                   LoadBalancer  
IP:                     10.244.250.177
Port:                   <unnamed>       30790/TCP
NodePort:               <unnamed>       32194/TCP
Endpoints:              <none>
Session Affinity:       None
No events.`

Answer (score 2):

The LoadBalancer should be getting created automatically.

There might be IAM policy issues preventing the load balancer from being created (see [Issue #10692](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/10692)).

If that isn't the problem, looking for errors in `/var/log/kube-controller-manager.log` on the master VM may give you an idea of what is going wrong.

Comment: i forgot to say that we use juju to deploy kubernetes. also i ahve found the following error message - _No cloud provider specified_. seems juju didn't setup some varianbles

Comment: similar issue without answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31616916/how-to-access-kubernetes-service-load-balancer-with-juju

Comment: The kube-controller-manager has to be run with `--cloud-provider=aws` in order to manage AWS resources. I'm not sure how this works with juju.

Comment: do i need to provide some AWS credentials/configuration file for aws provider

Comment: A lot of the deployment details are handled by `KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=AWS`. A lot of that is not going to work the same using `KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=JUJU` I've added the Juju tag to the question. Maybe @lazyPower or @matt-bruzek can chime in (they did most/all of the kubernetes juju support).

Answer (score 0):

This step is different whether you are using kubernetes over google cloud (where External IP is shown by issuing kubectl get svc ) or over amazon aws.   After launching your cluster (aws or gcloud) then deploying your app using kubectl create -f some-deployment.yaml you issue

```
kubectl expose rs your-pod-name  --type="LoadBalancer"
```

to expose your app ... then chill a few minutes until command

```
kubectl get pods
```

responds back with column STATUS has value Running ... only then issue

```
kubectl get svc
```

which after a few minutes will show EXTERNAL-IP on gcloud as per

```
NAME                       CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP       PORT(S)                   AGE
kubernetes                 10.123.240.1     <none>            443/TCP                   10m
loudspeed-deployment-210   10.123.247.54    104.196.113.166   3000/TCP,80/TCP,443/TCP   1m
mongo                      10.123.244.245   <none>            27017/TCP                 5m
```

whereas on aws the EXTERNAL-IP will partially display the URL of your LoadBalancer Ingress  ...  to see the full URL just issue

```
kubectl describe svc
```

typical output would be

```
Labels:         app=my-cool-app,pod-template-hash=494629853
Selector:       app=my-cool-app,pod-template-hash=494629853
Type:           LoadBalancer
IP:         10.0.154.138
LoadBalancer Ingress:   a53bigscarystring33e-20075.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Port:           port-1  80/TCP
NodePort:       port-1  30487/TCP
Endpoints:      10.244.0.3:80
Port:           port-2  443/TCP
NodePort:       port-2  32698/TCP
Endpoints:      10.244.0.3:443
Session Affinity:   None
Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From            SubobjectPath   Type        Reason          Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----            -------------   --------    ------          -------
  14m       14m     1   {service-controller }           Normal      CreatingLoadBalancer    Creating load balancer
  13m       13m     1   {service-controller }           Normal      CreatedLoadBalancer Created load balancer


Name:           mongo
Labels:         name=mongo
Selector:       name=mongo
Type:           ClusterIP
IP:         10.0.63.81
Port:           <unset> 27017/TCP
Endpoints:      10.244.0.4:27017
Session Affinity:   None
No events.
```

note in above value of

```
    LoadBalancer Ingress:   a53bigscarystring33e-20075.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

that is your External URL which is visible from command line using

```
curl a53bigscarystring33e-20075.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

and is typically mapped to your publicly visible domain in your aws Route 53 console on the Resource Type A auto refreshed picklist

See details like ( we do not automatically open NodePort services in the AWS firewall) https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.3/docs/design/aws_under_the_hood.md